# unbound redirect all traffic

Tags: linux, dns

I am trying to use wildcards to redirect certain sites through our proxy.
Is there a way to either:
(a) blanket redirect via a wildcard all domains ending in .nl
(b) redirect every single dns request via the proxy server?

My current conf for redirects looks something like:

```
local-zone: "co.uk." transparent
# local-zone: "fcod.llnwd.net." transparent
local-zone: "bbc.co.uk." redirect
local-data: "bbc.co.uk. 600 IN A 109.xx.xxx.xxx"
local-zone: "bbc.com." redirect
local-data: "bbc.com. 600 IN A 109.xx.xxx.xxx"
local-zone: "zattoo.com." redirect
local-data: "zattoo.com. 600 IN A 109.xx.xxx.xxx"
local-zone: "lovefilm.com." redirect
local-data: "lovefilm.com. 600 IN A 109.xx.xxx.xxx"
local-zone: "uktv.co.uk." redirect
local-data: "uktv.co.uk. 600 IN A 109.xx.xxx.xxx"
local-zone: "williamhill.com." redirect
local-data: "williamhill.com. 600 IN A 109.xx.xxx.xxx"
local-zone: "eurosport.com." redirect
local-data: "eurosport.com. 600 IN A 109.xx.xxx.xxx"
local-zone: "netflix.com." redirect
```

Comment: Server related questions can be asked at: http://serverfault.com/

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question, then you could add a

```
local-data: ".nl. 600 IN A 109.xx.xxx.xxx"
local-zone: ".nl." redirect
```

which should redirect the top of the hierarchy (or *wildcard*) the ".nl" top-level domain.